# Changing RadioButton backgound color on mouse hover and mouse leave all at once in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I have a program that has a lot of `RadioButtons`. I want to change the background color of each on mouse hover and reset the background color to transparent on mouse leave, all at once.

I know I can use the `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` event of each `RadioButton` but the code would be lengthy if I do it that way because there are too many RadioButtons.

Comment: Are these all on a panel, form etc...?

Comment: they are in groupboxes and all groupboxes are in the same form sir.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, it could be done in a different way, but I modified something I had to fit your needs... This is recursion by the way, dig into a control if it contains a radiobutton we can change it and so on...

***This is tried and tested***

```
 Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim rButton As New List(Of Control)

    For Each rd As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton In LoopControls(rButton, Me, GetType(System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton))
        AddHandler rd.MouseHover, AddressOf Me.ChangeColor
        AddHandler rd.MouseLeave, AddressOf Me.Transparent
    Next

End Sub

Public Shared Function LoopControls(ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal parent As Control, ByVal ctrlType As System.Type) As List(Of Control)
    If parent Is Nothing Then Return list
    If parent.GetType Is ctrlType Then
        list.Add(parent)
    End If

    For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
        LoopControls(list, child, ctrlType)
    Next
    Return list
End Function

Private Sub Transparent()
    Dim rButton As New List(Of Control)

    For Each rd As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton In LoopControls(rButton, Me, GetType(System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton))
        rd.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim rButton As New List(Of Control)

    For Each rd As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton In LoopControls(rButton, Me, GetType(System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton))
        rd.BackColor = Color.Red
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: i'm sorry if my question was not stated clearly, but this code changes the backcolor of all radiobuttons. what i need is, for each mousehover in each radiobutton, the backcolor changes. only the radiobutton that the mouse is hovering will change backcolor. i hope you get what i mean.

Comment: This does all them at once, not sure what your doing but it works for me for all of them, not just one. Are you just wanting to change for only the one it's over? If so you'll have to do it for each one...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the **MouseEnter** event instead of MouseHover:

```
Public Class Form

    Private radioButtonsList As List(Of RadioButton)

    Private Sub Form_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        For Each rb As RadioButton In Me.radioButtonsList
            RemoveHandler rb.MouseEnter, AddressOf Me.RadioButtons_MouseEnter
            RemoveHandler rb.MouseLeave, AddressOf Me.RadioButtons_MouseLeave
        Next

        Me.radioButtonsList = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.radioButtonsList = New List(Of RadioButton)
        Me.GetAllRadioButtonsFromMe()

        For Each rb As RadioButton In Me.radioButtonsList
            AddHandler rb.MouseEnter, AddressOf Me.RadioButtons_MouseEnter
            AddHandler rb.MouseLeave, AddressOf Me.RadioButtons_MouseLeave
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetAllRadioButtonsFromMe()
        Dim ctl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
        While ctl IsNot Nothing
            If TypeOf ctl Is RadioButton Then
                Me.radioButtonsList.Add(ctl)
            End If
            ctl = Me.GetNextControl(ctl, True)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButtons_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
        rb.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButtons_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
        rb.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub
End Class
```